# How to rename bones without renaming vertex groups?

Tags: armature, bones

I'm making a model which is covered with panels that each can move individually, and some of these panels need to rotate, but not all, so some of them need a rotation controller bone at the end. I'm not entirely sure which ones will end up needing rotation, though.

Basically what I'm wondering is: Can I rename a bone without renaming the corresponding vertex group(without deleting and remaking the bone)?

Comment: do you mean you want to be able to change the bone's name without automatically changing the vertex group's name?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.